# Reset camera button?

Tags: javascript, three.js

How to make camera rotate smoothly to it's original position when the html button is pressed?   ` (if cannot make it smooth please make it back to original position by anyway)

Button is look like this: `<button type="button" onclick="resetcamera();">RESET CAMERA!</button>`

Here the [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MqmTx/5/) please add reset camera into the button.

Thanks.

Comment: SO is for questions and problems, not for asking for people to do YOUR work! 

Concerning your theoretical problem: 
If there is no reset implemented in your camera controls, then save the cameras start position and viewing direction.
2) On Reset: Get the Difference in position and viewing direction and interpolate the movement back in some way.
Use Tween.js for example for smooth animation/ value interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does it instantly

http://jsfiddle.net/gZ6eB/

```
function resetcamera() {

    camera.position.set(0,0,500);

}
```

Comment: Yes, that's right, thank you very much, sorry people for bad question because i haven't much experiment in asking, again, thanks @spassvogel.